# ASP.net MVC 5 Add data to multiple tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Hi thank you all for assisting me. I am very new to ASP.net MVC and EF and am playing around to do  some real project. I would really appreciate if someone could please guide me of how I can insert data into two tables in SQL with one to many relationships. 
I have a requirement where I need to add multiple families to one behavior case.

- tblCase [case_id] [case_no]
- tblFamily [family_id] [first_name] [last_name] [case_id]

After following an online tutorial I am able to add multiple families but I can not get my head around how to:

1. Add a new case -> retrieve the last inserted case_id
2. Add all the families with the last inserted case_id in one submit button click.

My view looks like the following:

```
@model List<TestMVC.Family>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "BulkData";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<style>
td {
   padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<div style="width:700px; padding:5px; background-color:white;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("BulkData", "Save", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
       <div style="border:solid 1px green">
           @ViewBag.Message
       </div>
    }

    <div id="dvCase">
       <table>
           <tr>
               <td>Case Name</td>
               <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>Case No</td>
               <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </div>

   <div><a href="#" id="addNew">Add New</a></div>
   <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tr>
           <th>First Name</th>
           <th>Last Name</th>
           <th>Case Id</th>
           <th></th>
       </tr>
       @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {
           int j = 0;
           foreach (var i in Model)
            {
               <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                   <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].firstName)</td>
                   <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].lastName)</td>
                   <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].case_id)</td>
                   <td>
                       @if (j > 0)
                        {
                           <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                        }
                   </td>
               </tr>


                        j++;
            }
        }
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
</div>
```

and my controller looks like :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestMVC.Controllers
{
 public class SaveController : Controller
 {
   //
   // GET: /Save/
   public ActionResult BulkData()
    {
Case bc = new Case {case_id=0,case_no=""};           
// This is only for show by default one row for insert data to the database
       List<Family> ci = new List<Family> { new Family { family_id = 0, firstName = "", lastName = "", case_id= 0 } };
       return View(ci);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult BulkData(List<Family> ci)
    {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           using (FamilyContext dc = new FamilyContext())
            {
               var behaveCase = new Case();
               behaveCase.case_no = "1234";
               dc.Cases.add(behaveCase);
               foreach (var i in ci)
                {
                   i.Case = behaveCase;                    
                   dc.Families.Add(i);
                }
                dc.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "Data successfully saved!";
                ModelState.Clear();
                ci = new List<Family> { new Family { family_id = 0, firstName = "", lastName = "", case_id = 0 } };
            }
        }
       return View(ci);
    }
   }
}
```

and my model definitions

```
namespace TestMVC
{
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Case
{
   public Case()
    {
       this.Families = new HashSet<Family>();
    }

    public int case_id { get; set; }
   public string case_no { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Family> Families { get; set; }
}
}

namespace TestMVC
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Family
{
   public int family_id { get; set; }
   public string firstName { get; set; }
   public string lastName { get; set; }
   public int case_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Case Case { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Show us your models definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model which is added that is 'i' over here : dc.Families.Add(i); when dc.SaveChanges() called it will modify 'i' with its primary key as :

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       using (FamilyContext dc = new FamilyContext())
        {
           var behaveCase = new Case();
           behaveCase.case_no = "1234";
           dc.Cases.add(behaveCase);
           dc.SaveChanges(); // Save Changes Occurred. primary key in inserted in behaveCase
           int pk = behaveCase.case_id;  // You can get primary key of your inserted row
           foreach (var i in ci)
            {
               i.Case = behaveCase;                    
               dc.Families.Add(i);
               dc.SaveChanges(); // Save Changes Occured. Primary key of i is inserted
               int pkFam = i.family_id; // You can get primary key of your inserted row
            }

            ViewBag.Message = "Data successfully saved!";
            ModelState.Clear();
            ci = new List<Family> { new Family { family_id = 0, firstName = "", lastName = "", case_id = 0 } };
        }
    }
```